# How to replace Notepad with Sublime Text 3

Tags: text-editors, sublime-text-3, notepad

Is there a way to completely replace Notepad with Sublime Text 3, i.e., the files that would normally open with Notepad should open with Sublime Text 3, not just with .`.txt` files.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Notepad Replacer](https://www.binaryfortress.com/NotepadReplacer/), choose `sublime_text.exe`, and keep it installed.

Uninstall it if you want to restore Notepad as the default editor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to change the windows registry using Command Prompt, and then instruct the computer to open the Notepad opening files instead with Sublime Text 3.

Run CMD as administrator and enter the following command:

```
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\notepad.exe" /v "Debugger" /t REG_SZ /d "\"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe\" -notepadStyleCmdline -z" /f
```

You can change the path to Sublime based on your PC's Sublime Path

Regard